# Artoolkit source code file cannot execute successfully in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, libcurl, artoolkit, .so

I downloaded the Artoolkit SDK in https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5
And there is a directory called AndroidStudioProjects, which can be directly opened by using android studio.

I have configured all the jdk, android sdk, ndk.

However, those projects all have the error like this:

```
E/art: dlopen("/data/app/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARMovie-1/lib/arm/libARMovieNative.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libcurl.so" needed by "libARMovieNative.so"; caused by library "libcurl.so" not found
```

The main problem is could not load library "libcurl.so" needed by "libARMovieNative.so".

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to execute

```
$NDK/ndk-build
```

in the directory *AndroidStudioProjects/ARMovieProj/aRMovie/src/main/jni/*
which creates the libraries for a couple of architectures.
If you have not already done so far you have to execute the *build.sh* in the android directory of artoolkit.
If you don't want to build for every architecture feel free to modify

- android/jni/Application.mk
- ARMovieProj/aRMovie/src/main/jni/Application.mk

to for example

```
APP_ABI     := armeabi-v7a
```

Make sure the arMovie.gradle has got the following inside the android block

```
    android.sources.main.jniLibs {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        }
    }
```